# Laravel - real time notification with pusher

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to make real time notification in Laravel and I decided to use pusher for this purpose (with Pusher PHP Server) and Laravel events.I am wondering how I could check the database every second (ex. Checking for items with low stock count) and notify the user on the front-end with Javascript about these items.

For the meantime, I have an event and a listener which pushes data to the notification table and a Javascript for pusher instantiation and channel binding:

```
var pusher = new Pusher("{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}", 
  {
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true
  });

(function( $, pusher ) {

    var suppliesActionChannel = pusher.subscribe('is-critical');

    suppliesActionChannel.bind("client-supply-is-critical", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
})( jQuery, pusher);
```

I also made a controller which triggers the event:

```
class SupplyNotificationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Trigger event when the supplies are in critical point.
     *
     * @return none
     */
    public function criticalNotify()
    {
        $supply = Supply::select('ItemName', DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(ReceiptQty), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(IssuedQty), 0) AS BalanceQty'))->join('supply_stockcard_t', 'supply_stockcard_t.SupplyNo', '=', 'supply_t.SupplyNo')->having(DB::raw('BalanceQty'), '<=', 'ReOrderPoint')->groupBy('StockNo')->get();

        event(new SupplyInCriticalLevel('supply' => $supply));

        return response()->json('Success');
    }
}
```

I am thinking of calling this controller method via AJAX every second but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do the task. Should I proceed with this solution or is there are better options that Laravel offers?

Comment: Do you want to call `criticalNotify` with AJAX from client side?

Comment: @Dmitry yes that's what I'm planning to do. But I'm not sure if that's good practice.